# ImageView onClickListener is not working

Tags: android

I have two ImageViews, one text field and one WebView in a LinearLayout. My ImageView listener is not working. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="back"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="forward"
        android:src="@drawable/back_icon"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adressBar"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ems="10" >
    </EditText>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my Java code. I should point out that the Log.d statement is not firing, so it is definitely not getting called:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        L.d(">>onCreateView", "savedInstanceState null");
    }
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser,null);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    back =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("backkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk", "msg");

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

Comment: no need clickable=true for imageview

Comment: are you relying on the Log to understand if the onClick is fired?

Comment: yes whats wrong in that

Comment: Toast it  Hussanain ,

Comment: but why log is not working ??

Comment: toast is also not working plz help

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser, container, false);
ImageView back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageVIew1);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("backkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk", "msg");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate the view like

```
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browser, container, false);
back =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())
{
..
}
```

Comment: r u really clicking image? :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
back.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And implement onclicklistener.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with either way. There are several ways to slice an onion, the best way just depends on who is slicing it and which knife they prefer

Answer (score 0):

set to focusable false for all the views in your xml file. or setOnClickListener for imageview in onActivityCreated() method in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding `android:layout_width="44dp"` to make sure **user would have enough area to click on**. Then, you can align image content the way you wannt. In my case:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/locationImageView"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/locationText"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_edit_small_white"/>
```